# Remove username field from Django Allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm trying to remove the username field after overriding the Django Allauth package. I tried the following suggestions:

1. Set `ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None` and some more inside **settings.py** as following:

```py
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH = 8
```

2. Overriding User Model in **venv\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py**

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = "AUTH_USER_MODEL"
```

both failed, as when I run `py manage.py createsuperuser`, I still got the username field popping up:

```
Username (leave blank to use 'admin'):
```

How can I safely remove the username field while overriding Django Allauth?

Could you show me a way to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Both **django** and **django-allauth** has have the *username* and *email* field. And by you defining a **CutomUser** means you're trying to cutomize the default user model you don't have to re-declare the variables again.
Here is how your new `models.py` will look like

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Then update your *settings.py* with:

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False

ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False    # This removes the username field
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
```